# How can I implement caching in SharePoint custom web-parts?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

Here I am want to fetch data from SharePoint user profiles and there are approx 2-3K of records exist,how can i get it?

Comment: check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163182.aspx